# Marionette - Events being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having troubles handling events between my views and collections. In the below example you can find a short version of what does my webapp look like and how are the events being handled now.

What happens here is that when switching from **menu1** to **menu2** or even when going backwards, it causes that the "APP:change_city" event listener is stacked up. So when I then trigger this event , it calls the method `OnCityChange()` as many times as I switched between the menus.

I'm now not really sure whether I'm using the event aggregator (eMgr) correctly. 
Can anyone please assist?

**eMgr.js**

```
define(['backbone.wreqr'],function(Wreqr){
    "use strict";
    return new Wreqr.EventAggregator();
})
```

**AppRouter.js**

```
define(['marionette'],  function (Marionette) {
    "use strict";

    var AppRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            'menu1' : 'showMenu1',
            'menu1' : 'showMenu2'
        }
    });

    return AppRouter;
});
```

**AppControler.js**

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', '../eMgr'],  function (_, Backbone, Marionette, eMgr) {
    "use strict";

    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                console.log("AppRouter - Init")
            },

            showMenu1: function (city) {
                console.log(" [Info] [AppControler] opening Menu1");
                eMgr.trigger("APP:open_menu", { menu: "Menu1", city: city});
            },

            showMenu2: function (city) {
                console.log(" [Info] [AppControler] opening Menu2");
                eMgr.trigger("APP:open_menu", { menu: "Menu2", city: city});
            }
    });

    return Controller;
});
```

**App.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 'eMgr',  
    'layouts/MainMenu/layoutview.menu1',
    'layouts/MainMenu/layoutview.menu2',
    'controllers/AppController', 'routers/AppRouter'], 
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette,  eMgr,  
    lv_mainmenu1, lv_mainmenu2,
    AppController, AppRouter) {
    "use strict";

    var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();
    var controller = new AppController();

    MyApp.addRegions({
        .....
        mainmenu: '#main_menu',
        .....
    });

    MyApp.listenTo(eMgr, "menu_changed",function(eData){
        switch(eData.menu){
            case "Menu1":
                MyApp.mainmenu.show(new lv_mainmenu1(eData));
                break;
            case "Menu2": 
                MyApp.mainmenu.show(new lv_mainmenu2(eData));
                break;
        }
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(options) {
        var router = new AppRouter({
          controller : controller
        });
    });


    MyApp.on("start", function(){
      if (Backbone.history){
          Backbone.history.start();
      }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        MyApp.start();
    });
});
```

**layoutview.menu1.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 
            'templates/template.mainmenu', 
            'layouts/MainMenu/collectionview.categories'],
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, t_Menus, c_Categories, cv_Categories) {
    "use strict";
    var Menu1LayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

        template: t_Menus['menu1'],

        regions: {
            menu : '#menu'
        },

        initialize: function(options){
            this.city = options.city
        },


        onRender: function(){
        },

        onShow: function(){
            this.menu.show(new cv_Categories({city:this.city}));
        }
    });

    return Menu1LayoutView;
});
```

**collectionview.categories.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette',
    'layouts/MainMenu/compositeview.subcategories',
    'collections/MainMenu/MM.collection.categories'], 
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, cv_Subcategories, c_Categories) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoriesCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        initialize: function(options){
            this.collection = new c_Categories([], {city: options.city});
        },

        getChildView: function(model){
            return cv_Subcategories;
        },

        onRender: function(){
        },
         onShow: function(){
        }
    });

    return CategoriesCollectionView;
});
```

This is where all the categorie's data are fetched from , it also re-fetches the data once the `APP:change_city` event is being triggered.

**MM.collection.categories.js**

```
    define([ 'underscore',  'backbone', 'eMgr','models/MainMenu/MM.model.category'], function(_, Backbone, eMgr, m_Category){
  var CategoriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: m_Category,

    initialize: function(attr, opts) {
        this.city = opts.city;
        this.fetch();
        eMgr.once("APP:change_city", this.OnCityChange, this)
    },

    url: function(){
        return 'AF_GetCategories?city='+this.city;
    },

    OnCityChange: function(eData){
        /// this is the part which is being called multiple times !!!!!   ////
        /// when checking eMgr's events , it shows that the events are stacking up .. 
        this.url= 'AF_GetCategories?city='+eData.city;
        this.fetch();
    }
  });

  return CategoriesCollection;
});
```

**compositeview.subcategories.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette',
    'templates/template.mainmenu', 
    'layouts/MainMenu/itemview.subcategory'], 
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, t_MainMenu, iv_Subcategory) {
    "use strict";
    var SubcategoriesCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        template: t_Menus['subcategorieslayout'],

        childViewContainer: "#category-wrapper",

        getChildView: function(model){
            return iv_Subcategory;
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.collection = this.model.get("subcategories");
        },


        onRender: function(){
        },

        onShow: function(){
            this.$el.find("#loading").fadeOut(150);
        }
    });

    return SubcategoriesCompositeView;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a conclusion that keeping the event listeners `this.listenTo("custom_event", this.do_something)` in either model or collection isn't a good idea. The events weren't cleaned up properly while switching between **menu1** and **menu2**. It only worked when I manually called `eMgr.stopListening()`  before loading any views.

So I tried moving all the event listeners from `models/collections` to their views and Voila!...it all worked! Events are no longer being triggered multiple times as before.